# How to debug GQL queries in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some custom user model, and I count the number of users with name Joe:

```
c = UserModel.all().filter('name =', 'Joe').count()
```

Even though I know there is a Joe in the datastore, there is some mistake witch makes c == 0.

This is a problem I'm dealing with, however the biggest problem is that I don't know how to debug this.

I would like to get some query and visualise it somehow, so that I can understand what is there and why Joe is not there:

```
v = magically_visualise_contents_of(UserModel.all().filter('name =','Joe'))

handler.response.out.write(v)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly in the datastore viewer by GQL? That usually helps identify minor issues

Comment: ie: SELECT * FROM UserModel WHERE name = 'Joe'

Comment: @Nick you should add this as an answer because, imho, it's a valid answer

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query directly in the datastore viewer by GQL.
That usually helps identify minor issues, for example:

```
 SELECT * FROM UserModel WHERE name = 'Joe'
```

Also, one common mistake with string matching is whitespace characters in the data, like `"Joe "`.